# Why does getattr() exit a program when it raises an exception inside a try statement?

Tags: python, import, exit, try-except, getattr

I have a file called `table_builders.py` where I have defined multiple classes. Inside another script, I am importing them in a loop. The classes that I am trying to import are listed in `builders_list`.

Below is how I am doing the import.

```
import table_builders

for b in builders_list:
    try:
        globals()[b] = getattr(table_builders, b)
        print(f'Successfully imported {b}')
    except ImportError as e:
        print(f'\nError importing {b}. \n{e}')
```

Not all of the classes in `builders_list` have been defined in `table_builders.py` yet. But since I am doing the import inside a `try:` statement, I would expect the code to import all that have been defined, and skip over the ones that haven't been defined.

What is happening, however, is that the program is exiting as soon as the first import fails. The terminal shows:

```
Successfully imported CustomersBuilder
Successfully imported FacilitiesBuilder
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ......
    globals()[b] = getattr(table_builders, b)

AttributeError: module 'table_builders' has no attribute 'CustomerFulfillmentPoliciesBuilder'
```

Note that the print statement inside `except` never actually prints.

Why is getattr() exiting my program when it throws an error inside of a try: statement?

Is there another way to do the import so that the program doesn't exit when the import fails?

Thank you!

Comment: You catch `ImportError`, but you got an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Right.  The import is finished as soon as the `import` statement is done.  In your mind, you might be importing data from that module, but that's not a Python `import`.

Comment: You aren't doing an import in a loop anywhere, you are simply accessing an attribute on an *already imported module*, which won't raise an `ImportError` if that attribute doesn't exist, and instead, will raise an `AttributeError`, which is clearly described in the error message

Comment: ‍♂️ Wow, thank you! Glad it was a simple fix.

Comment: Btw, you can answer and accept your own question if you want!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who commented below the original post. I was catching the wrong error (and not actually importing in a loop).